# SOQL in Developer Console returns just one record for FieldDefinition object

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console

Why does the Developer Console return just one record in a scratch org when I query the FieldDefinition object?

[image]

The header says 46 rows, but it shows only one in the data table.

Comment: Check your FLS?

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) and testing the query together with your query multiple times. I found that, you have to **remove the Id field** from the query in order to fetch all the rows; which in your case the query should be:

```
SELECT DeveloperName,
    QualifiedApiName,
    MasterLabel
  FROM FieldDefinition
  WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'contact'
```

Comment: Great finding. Any suggestion as to why ID needs to be dropped? I am guessing because there is no actual stored ID (the one in the screenshot is the ID placeholder) and that the dev console stores the results in a map by ID - so since all the records are reported with the same fake ID, only one gets kept for display.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW, at first I was wondering the same on why ID needs to be dropped. But, I think what you have said seem to be the case, upon querying Id for 2 different rows (with different DeveloperName), it seems yes their Id's are the same. I think that is why only one is being displayed. Many thanks!

Comment: If you use a soql query from say workbench or your IDE, the value of the ID column for all 46 records is `000000000000000AAA`. So, the Id only needs to be dropped in the DevConsole usecase